# Solr Spell-checking and suggester configuration

Tags: magento, solr

I'm trying to integrate solr with Magento EE 1.14 on my local server.

**What I did so far?**

- Installed solr 3.6.2.
- Copied files from magentoroot/lib/Apache/Solr/Conf to solrroot/example/solr/conf
- started start.jar file
- re-indexed all data through cmd .
- In solrconfig.xml my default search is 
  `<defaultSearchField>sku</defaultSearchField>`

  and it is working fine in Magento for spell-checking .

**What issue I'm having?**

When I enter : * : in solr admin panel and hit search, I'm getting 404 at localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=%3A*%3A&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

```
Problem accessing /solr/select/. Reason:

null
```

If I hit localhost:8983/solr/spell?q=abc%20ultrashar&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.build=true , it gives Error 500.

```
Problem accessing /solr/spell. Reason:

    null
```

I want to configure search, spell-checking, auto-complete, facets for most of the product attributes(name, sku, price, qty, etc) through solrconfig.xml and schema.xml but I don't know exactly what all modification I have to do. Can someone suggest what all modification I've to do to work it with Magento?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems. I found this url to be helpful. You shouldnt have to change any Solr configurations. You need to modify the theme to include files to allow the site to control the output of the results. Basically you need to have recommendations.phtml and suggestions.phtml included in your theme.

https://www.quora.com/I-have-installed-Solr-with-Magento-EE-How-can-I-configure-auto-suggest-and-spell-check